# Install Mac OS on Macbook Air running only Windows 7

Tags: installation, operating-systems, macbook

My girlfriends Late 2010 Macbook Air, only has Windows 7 installed on it.

I am now taking it over and want to get rid of Windows and only have Mac OS. Problem is all the stuff I can find online, presupposes that you have Mac OS on the machine in order to create the bootable USB.

How do I do this? If I download a DMG file with OS X Maverick on it, how do I create a bootable USB installer of Mac OS X from within Windows 7?

Any help much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether or not a firmware update was installed, this model is able to use recovery mode. See more info here: https://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/ Or just try to boot while holding Command + R.

If it works, you don't need any USB drives, you just need an internet connection.